# How to change the default EGit clone directory

Tags: eclipse, egit

Is there a way I can change the default directory where EGit will clone git repositories I import (clone)?

It is currently set to `~/git` and I really don't want to click through a whole directory system each time I do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the *Clone Git Repository* wizard, EGit suggests to clone into `$home/git`.

You can change the default repository folder under *Window* > *Preferences* > *Team* > *Git*

[image]

Comment: Not sure how I missed that - I must have gone through them settings several times. Thanks.